# Put do catch block in array

Tags: swift, sqlite

I need to to fill a cell with Sqlite data from a file. I have this code that reads the db and prints stuff (for testing), now I want to use it to to fill the cell values (a list of countries in a UIPickerView) but in order to do so I need the try Connection to be in a Do Catch block, and the [ ] does not accept Do Catch blocks. How can I do this?

```
do {
    // Database Connection
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "location", ofType: "sqlite")!
    db = try Connection(path, readonly: true)

    // Defino los parametros de la DB
    let code = Expression<Int64>("code")
    let name = Expression<String>("name")
    let num_levels = Expression<Int64>("num_levels")
    let levels_desc = Expression<String>("levels_desc")
    let paises = Table("country")

    for pais in try db.prepare(paises) {
        print("code: \(pais[code]), name: \(pais[name]), num_levels: \(pais[num_levels]), levels_desc: \(pais[levels_desc])")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error occurred \(error)")
}

cell.values = [


]
```

Comment: You shouldn’t store values in cells directly from the dB response, store the dB response in an array (as a class property) and then have your cells use that array as data source

Comment: Would you mind telling me how you would do it? I am completely clueless here.